# IIS, Visual Studio 2010: How to exclude files from being in my IIS folder?

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2010, virtual-directory

I have a Visual Studio solution that is linked to an IIS Virtual Directory. Is there any way to exclude files/folders from my solution from showing up in the IIS Virtual Directory? Oh, and currently I'm running IISV5.1, but on the deployed server it'll probably be IIS6 or II7.

Also, to that point... are there any files/folders that **ARE** required to stay? Here's a sample of my Virtual Directory:

- App_Data\
- bin\
- bin\MyProject.dll
- bin\MyProject.pdb
- bin\MyCommons.dll
- bin\MyCommons.pdb
- obj\
- obj\Debug\
- obj\Debug\TempPE\
- obj\Debug\MyProject.dll
- obj\Debug\MyProject.pdb
- obj\Debug\MyProject.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
- obj\Debug\DesignTimeResolveAssemblyReferencesInput.cache
- Properties\
- Proprties\AssemblyInfo.cs
- Service References\
- MyProject.csproj
- Update.svc
- Update.cs
- web.config
- Web.Debug.config
- Web.Release.config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In file explorer change the hidden attribute of the folders and files that you don't want to display in the VS. 
When you publish from visual studio it will prepare all the things he must have to run it in a different server.

Comment: I tried the publish feature and it condenses it down into just the DLL files and config files you need.